# ROR: Adding comments to post issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I am currently learning rails and am facing a problem when I try to add a comment. 
If user A comments under user B's post, the comment will display under all user A's posts rather than under the specific post of user B.

I think the problem has to do with the view page rather than how the comment is being saved to the database.

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :pin
end
```

**comments.controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

 before_action :set_pin

 def create  
    @comment = @pin.user.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id

    if @comment.save
    redirect_to root_path
    else
        render root_path
    end
 end

 private

 def comment_params  
   params.require(:comment).permit(:content)
 end

 def set_pin  
  @pin = Pin.find(params[:pin_id])
 end 
end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
    - if pin.user.comments
                    - pin.user.comments.each do |comment|
                        .commentContainer
                            %h4.desc
                                %strong
                                    =link_to (pin.user.Username), user_path(pin.user_id)
                                = comment.content
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

EDIT.

Comments table:

```
0|id|INTEGER|1||1
1|user_id|integer|0||0
2|pin_id|integer|0||0
3|content|text|0||0
4|created_at|datetime|1||0
5|updated_at|datetime|1||0

sqlite> select * from comments;
1|15||Nice shot!|2017-02-07 16:13:06.707372|2017-02-07 16:13:06.707372
2|15||Cool pic|2017-02-07 16:25:27.780830|2017-02-07 16:25:27.780830
3|14||test|2017-02-08 14:08:17.397782|2017-02-08 14:08:17.397782
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are correct, the issue is just how you are displaying them.

You want to remove the user from displaying the comments.  What you want to do is show the list of comments belonging to the pin and then just access the user's data through that.

```
- if pin.comments
  - pin.comments.each do |comment|
      .commentContainer
      %h4.desc
      %strong
         =link_to (comment.user.Username),user_path(comment.user.user_id)
      = comment.content
```

The line

```
- pin.comments.each do |comment|
```

Will show all comments belonging to that pin, regardless of the user.  Then you access the user's data through it's relationship with the comment inside.

```
(comment.user.Username)
```

Also make sure that all the relationships go both ways.

Pin.rb

```
has_many :comments
```

User.rb

```
has_many :comments
```

Comment: When I try that I get a undefined method error :undefined method comments for #<Pin:0x9560868>  Another newbie mistake but I don't know what is causing the error. Why does it work when I put `pin.user.comments` but not when I put `pin.comments` ?

Comment: Can you verify that the pin id is getting saved when you save the comment?  Like is there data in the db column?

Comment: I think having the user in the create method part might be the issue too, but I am not sure, are you working form an online tutorial?

Comment: Do you have the relationship established in the pin model as well.  "has_many :comments" ?

Comment: that was the reason! I didn't have "has_many :comments". Thanks alot!